# does order matter when two different derivations are to be made for ambiguous grammar

Tags: automata

E ->  E + E | E * E | (E) | a

Derivation for ( (a+a) * a)

Question : Show that the grammar is ambiguous by sparse tree method

Now, I have derived two derivation using left most derivation

but it results in like this
1st : **((a+a) * a)**
2nd : **(a * (a+a))**

is this correct or the order should also be same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deriving *different* strings. The definition of ambiguity asks for the *very same string*.

In this case, that they "mean the same thing" in algebra, due to the commutative law for multiplication, is completely off topic.

Comment: Thanks for help. Also could you tell me how to drive the second one?Or is this unambiguous grammar.